Understanding Tzibah
In 2 Samuel 9 we meet a man named Tzibah who is a servant of the house of Saul. David consults him to find out if there are any living descendants from the line of Saul.
If there were no living descendants from the line of Saul how could Tzibah be a servant of the house of Saul, there would be no house of Saul. Furthermore, it would seem that Tzibah is not in fact serving Mephiboshet (the grandson of Saul, the person in question) since Mephiboshet is in the house of Machir and it is only in v9-10 that Tzibah is instructed to serve him.
Perhaps a charitable reading would posit that Tzibah was also in the house of Machir, serving Mephiboshet and David was just 'making it official'. But that would require David and his servants to know of Tzibah, his location, but not know that Mephiboshet was alive and being served in that same location. And/or, not really giving Mephiboshet anything new, other than meals by the king. Possible, but I would prefer to find an alternative explanation.

The Book of Shmuel, like pretty much the rest of Tanach, wasn't written in real-time (e.g., Bava Batra 15a indicates that the book was written in stages). The title "servant of the House of Shaul" either refers to Tziva having been a former servant of that clan, or the title was given later, once he was commanded by David to serve Mefiboshet. Given the fact that: a. David decided to consult him regarding possible survivors of that clan, b. Tziva knew to give a detailed answer to the question, and c. David commanded him to return to his post as servant of the clan (Shmuel 2:9:9-10), the former option is the most likely.
Regarding the issue raised in your last paragraph, Malbim on Shmuel 2:9:1 asks how could it be that David, who was the son-in-law of Shaul (through his wife Michal, daughter of Shaul) and a former member of his household, plus best friend of Yonatan, did not know who in that family was still alive. His answer is that the other members of the clan went into hiding because they feared for their lives. They were afraid that David intended to do away with the entire rival household like other ancient (and frankly, modern) kings did (and do). This explains why David knew of Tziva but not of Mefiboshet's survival. Tziva was merely a servant and not important enough to be considered a serious contender for the crown. But Mefiboshet was certainly influential enough to pose a political threat to David. Interestingly Mefiboshet was actually found to be hiding in a prominent Gadite city, Lo-Davar,1 hosted by Machir ben Amiel, who went on to become one of David's allies.2

1 Other than mentions in David's story, it was also prominent enough to be mentioned as part of the Gadite territory in Yehoshua 13:26 and as one of two prominent Transjordanian cities (re)conquered by the Kingdom of Israel, perhaps around the time of Yerov'am II. See: Amos 6:13.
2 Interestingly, knowing that Tziva didn't like serving Shaul's household, it's possible that Tziva pointedly mentioned the fact that Mefiboshet was in a key Transjordanian city because he was supposedly orchestrating a rebellion against David.
